# Unable to create a new dataframe with a preset conditions

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have tried this several times with the same error "The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all()."

Code:

```
df = {'category': ['retail', 'retail', 'airtime', 'electronic', 'retail', 'electronic', 
'retail', 'retail','airtime'],
'default': [0, 1, 1, 1,0,1,1,1,0],
'year': [2011, 2013, 2014, 2015,2016,2017,2018,2010,2009],
'value': [6000, 6500, 3000, 1200,3200,4530,2100,1000,3400]}
df = pd.DataFrame(df)
df

def Default_prob(x):
    if x>=2800:
       return 1
    else:
       return 0
 df["Default_prob"]=df["value"].apply(Default_prob)

def Default_category(x):
    if x=="retail":
       return 1
    else:
    return 0  
df["Default_category"]=df["category"].apply(Default_category)

df['probability'] = 0
df.loc[df['Default_prob'] == 1 & df['Default_category'] == 1, 'probability'] = 1

df
```

The desired output should look like this
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Try:**

```
df.loc[(df['Default_prob'] == 1) & (df['Default_category'] == 1), 'probability'] = 1
```

Just filtering (with no assignment) shows:

```
df.loc[(df['Default_prob'] == 1) & (df['Default_category'] == 1), 'probability']
0    1
1    1
4    1
Name: probability, dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 0):

The error message is quite confusing in this case indeed and does not exactly indicate what the problem is.

While usually in python using multiple boolean comparisons does not require parentheses:

```py
x = 1
y = 1
x == 1 & y == 1   # True
```

`numpy` is rather picky about this syntax.

```py
import numpy as np
xx = np.array([1, 0])
yy = np.array([1, 1])
xx==1 & yy==1  # ValueError
(xx==1) & (yy==1)  # array([ True, False])
```

as `pandas` is built on top of numpy arrays this behavior propagates to subsetting a dataset. So, the solution, as @MDR proposed, is

```py
df.loc[(df['Default_prob'] == 1) & (df['Default_category'] == 1), 'probability'] = 1
```